# Raffle winner selection

Tags: probability, random-variables, systems-of-equations, random

I am creating a raffle with 8191 numbers, ranging from 1 to 8191. Once the raffle is completed I want to select 63 winners, in a way that people could verify how I got that result. For this, I thought of using the numbers from the next lottery, perform some equations on the lottery result ( example: 1, 3, 8, 23, 34, 56) generating those 63 numbers for my own raffle. Like this people could validate the randomness of this selection by performing the same equation. Is this possible? Or if you have another random way that I could select those 63 winners. I know there are a few websites that perform random numbers selection, but I would like to make something so that people are able to see under the hood how we got these results.

Comment: This is not clear.  If the winning numbers can be predicted by some formula, how can they be "random"?   A standard mechanism is to use some visibly chaotic event (like numbered ping pong balls tossed around by air currents) to choose the numbers.  But of course any mechanism is subject to tampering.

Comment: Bascially you are looking for a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG), and will use upcoming lottery numbers as a public source of real randomness to form the seed for the PRNG from which it will generate the 63 winners.

Comment: You could try [this online PRNG](https://leventozturk.com/engineering/random/) for example.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I just need to understand the different formulas it has there, to know which one will give me the most honest spread across all users. If you happen to also possess this knowledge I'd gladly receive this from you. You've been so helpful already. Cheers

Comment: The PRNG algorithms there are well established and should be fine for this kind of thing. You could simply use the default Mersenne Twister algorithm, put in 138233456 (the lottery numbers strung together) as seed, set (min,max) to (1,8192), and 63 numbers of output, then press calculate. In the output just ignore the digits after the decimal point. If there are any duplicates, click Continue for some additional numbers.